# Get Windows 10 Icon not active

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

So I have the GW10 icon in my notification area icons menu, where I can select from the drop down menu one of three options. When selecting the "show icon and notifications" option, I get a response stating that this icon is not active. How do I get it to become active so that I may register to DL windows 10?

Comment: This is normal.  It will return eventually. Microsoft is doing a phase roll out of Windows 10.  If you cant wait use the Media Creation Tool and use that to upgrade your installation.

Comment: link for forced update: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Open the Notepad
2. Copy the following text and paste into the notepad

REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\UpgradeExperienceIndicators" /v UpgEx | findstr UpgEx
if "%errorlevel%" == "0" GOTO RunGWX
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Appraiser" /v UtcOnetimeSend /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
schtasks /run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"
:CompatCheckRunning
schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"
schtasks /query /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" | findstr Ready
if NOT "%errorlevel%" == "0" ping localhost >nul &goto :CompatCheckRunning
:RunGWX
schtasks /run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Setup\gwx\refreshgwxconfig"

3. Save it as ‘ReserveWindows10.cmd’ to a directory called temp or whatever you like in C drive.
4. Run the file by opening command prompt as administrator
5. Once your PC is compatible, you’ll see success message at the end and a schedule task will start to open the app...

If this does NOT work, try this:
Download this Batch File: [http://www.mediafire.com/download/yhs9s3rd7smsqi0/win10fix_full.zi](http:///www.mediafire.com/download/yhs9s3rd7smsqi0/win10fix_full.zip)p
Then run it as Administrator. TRY AT YOUR OWN RISK! THIS WILL CHANGE REGISTRY FILES AND SETTINGS!!

MilenniumEdition56
Info from: [Techdows.com](http://techdows.com/2015/06/how-to-enable-get-windows-10-app-icon-windows-7-or-8-1-taskbar.html)

Comment: This isn't going to work for the user.  I should know, my icon disappeared, and I run that exact command.  You are just rehashing the same information that has been shared in an existing question anyways.

Comment: And please learn how to quote properly. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)